# How to merge two pisaDocument file

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

Using xhtml2pdf  how can i append two 'pisaContext' object  python.

My requirement is to render two pages separately into 2 different pdf, and then merge return the merged pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I know that is a old question but I face this problem today, here is my solution using PyPDF2:

```py
from StringIO import StringIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

# html1 and html2 are strings with the html content.
# link_callback is a function that return the path of files requested in the PDF file


pdf1_file = StringIO()
pdf1 = pisa.pisaDocument(
    StringIO(html1.encode('UTF-8')),
    pdf1_file,
    link_callback=link_callback,
    encoding='UTF-8'
)

pdf2_file = StringIO()
pdf2 = pisa.pisaDocument(
    StringIO(html2.encode('UTF-8')),
    pdf2_file,
    link_callback=link_callback,
    encoding='UTF-8'
)

if not pdf1.err and not pdf2.err:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    merger.append(pdf1_file)
    merger.append(pdf2_file)
    merger.write("files_merged.pdf")
```

Basically, I render the two pisaDocuments in memory using `StringIO` and pass them to `PdfFileMerger` with the `append` method and finally, write to a file named "files_merged.pdf". You can also pass a `StringIO` instance to `write` method and do everything in memory:

```py
if not pdf1.err and not pdf2.err:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    merger.append(pdf1_file)
    merger.append(pdf2_file)
    output = StringIO()
    merger.write(output)
    file_content = output.getvalue()
```